# Use kohana ORM on zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, orm, kohana-3

I would like to know if there is a way to use kohana ORM module on zend framework. I really do not like zend's db_table model because it is over complicated to work with and there is not validation included.

I think validation should be included on the model not on separated forms, of course there are reasons of why this was made this way but in the case that I need, this is not useful.

I would apreciate any help from you guys.

Regards,
Teddy

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard people using Kohana ORM in Zend Framework .

Reasons are

1 ) Kohana itself is a framework . You can include Zend framework as a library if needed .

2 ) I am not sure whether Kohana ORM can be used as a standalone ORM . If so yes you can . Keep it in `libaray` folder and add the `autoloaderNamespaces` in `application.ini`. Zend is using Pear standard. So any library which uses the same can be done via the same trick. You can see how [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is included in Zend Framework from [ZendCasts.com](http://www.zendcasts.com/htmlpurifier-integration/2011/05/)

3 ) Many of the people who uses Zend are using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) from version 2 needs 5.3, [PHP Active Record](http://phpactiverecord.org) for 5.3, [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) for 5.2 + etc which are standalone .

Comment: thanks for the help Hari will look at the zendcasts.com page.